# external hyperlink in guidewire policy center

Tags: hyperlink, gosu, guidewire

I need to do an hyperlink to an external page in Guidewire Policy Center.
I am using a function in a gsx enhancement file that returns a String with the url according some parameters.

The problem is that I don't know how to use the url to redirect to another page.

Answer (score 1):

As Carlos mentioned you need to create / use an ExitPoint PCF.  The documentation is linked in his answer so I won't do it again, however in case it becomes invalid for some reason here's the long and short of it.

You need to create a new PCF file and make of type exitpoint
[image]

In there you make an exitPointParameter, fill out the necessary fields, and you're set.

Then you can put your link wherever you want and just put in the action `nameOfExitPointPCF.push("http://www.google.com")`

You can put other parameters in there, and it'll build it for you, just refer to the documentation.

For really simple external links, there's one called `ExternalUrl.pcf` that I assume is in the out of the box configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a ExitPoint PCF file. You can read about that in module documentation. Open the page with Firefox...

PolicyCenter/doc/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=Configuration Guide/pagefunc.34.4.html